# IEnumerable Concat Missing, does not contain a definition for 'Concat'

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

I have the following Class which inherits IEnumerable

```
public class LinesEnumerable : IEnumerable<Point>
{
    protected readonly IPointSeries _pointSeries;
    protected readonly ICoordinateCalculator<double> _xCoordinateCalculator;
    protected readonly ICoordinateCalculator<double> _yCoordinateCalculator;
    protected readonly bool _isDigitalLine;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="LinesEnumerable" /> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pointSeries">The point series.</param>
    /// <param name="xCoordinateCalculator">The x coordinate calculator.</param>
    /// <param name="yCoordinateCalculator">The y coordinate calculator.</param>
    /// <param name="isDigitalLine">if set to <c>true</c> return a digital line .</param>
    public LinesEnumerable(IPointSeries pointSeries, ICoordinateCalculator<double> xCoordinateCalculator, ICoordinateCalculator<double> yCoordinateCalculator, bool isDigitalLine)
    {
        _pointSeries = pointSeries;
        _xCoordinateCalculator = xCoordinateCalculator;
        _yCoordinateCalculator = yCoordinateCalculator;
        _isDigitalLine = isDigitalLine;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns an enumerator that iterates through a collection.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// An <see cref="T:System.Collections.IEnumerator" /> object that can be used to iterate through the collection.
    /// </returns>
    public virtual IEnumerator<Point> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _isDigitalLine ?
            (IEnumerator<Point>)new DigitalLinesIterator(_pointSeries, _xCoordinateCalculator, _yCoordinateCalculator) :
            new LinesIterator(_pointSeries, _xCoordinateCalculator, _yCoordinateCalculator);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns an enumerator that iterates through a collection.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// An <see cref="T:System.Collections.IEnumerator" /> object that can be used to iterate through the collection.
    /// </returns>
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

However, when I try to do the following:

```
linesEnumerable = linesEnumerable.Concat(new[] { new Point(viewportWidth, lastYCoordinate) });
```

it says 'System.Collections.IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'Concat' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Queryable.Concat(System.Linq.IQueryable, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable)' has some invalid arguments

I already have System.Linq namespace added

Anybody know why this is happening?

Comment: Make sure to use System.Linq namespace. It contains the Enumerable class which contains the extension methods for the IEnumerable class.

Comment: What's `linesEnumerable`? Is it `IEnumerable` or `IEnumerable<Point>`?

Comment: it's IEnumerable<Point>

Comment: I already have System.Linq Namespace

Answer (score 20):

The compiler will give this error when the two collections are of different types `T`. For example:

```
List<int> l1 = new List<int>();
List<string> l2 = new List<string>();

var l3 = l1.Concat(l2);
var l4 = l1.Union(l2);
```

The `Concat` and `Union` calls will result in the following compile-time errors respectively:

> 'List' does not contain a definition for 'Concat' and the best extension method overload 'Queryable.Concat(IQueryable, IEnumerable)' requires a receiver of type 'IQueryable'
>
> 'List' does not contain a definition for 'Union' and the best extension method overload 'Queryable.Union(IQueryable, IEnumerable)' requires a receiver of type 'IQueryable'

It is confusing because the message is misleading and VS intellisense recognizes the extension methods. The solution is that `l1` and `l2` must be lists of the same type `T`.

Comment: And I find that most often, I am trying to `Concat` an `IEnumerable<T>` and an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>` object. I have usually used `Select` where I have meant `SelectMany`.

Answer (score 7):

Well this won't help you but this question is the top result when you google the error so I'm going to say what my problem was.

I had the following classes:

```
class Group
class Row : Group
class Column : Group
```

I was trying to call Concat on an `IEnumerable<Row>` with an `IEnumerable<Column>` to get an `IEnumerable<Group>`. This doesn't work because you can't convert the columns to rows. The solution was to cast my `IEnumerable<Row>` to `IEnumerable<Group>`.

e.g. `rows.Cast<Group>().Concat(columns)`

Comment: This solution inspired me to look at the types of my collections to ensure they even can be concat-ed. While they are the same type, I was using an implicitly typed array with an explicitly typed array. Changing the implicit type to a explicit type fixed the error. So `(new byte[] { 0x00 }).Concat(new[] { 0x00 });` changes to `(new byte[] { 0x00 }).Concat(new byte[] { 0x00 });`